# Dataframe operations not working when triggered in a websocket call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, websocket

I have setup a websocket to read minute by minute data and it seems to work flawlessly. The data is stored in a DataFrame.

I have built a trigger point in which a defined function will be called if a certain data point is received. This defined function then makes calculations (such as the below).

```
def function(data_table):
    print(1)
    data_table[('ret')] = np.log(data_table[('close')] / data_table[('close')].shift(1))
    print(2)
    return data_table
```

I have placed print statements before and after the calculation as shown above to help troubleshoot.

It seems that the calculation step fails but I can't identify the reason why. (it prints 1 but not 2)

For testing the function above, I have also separately created a random dataset and it works perfectly fine, so it seems that its something to do with the fact that the calculation is attempted within the live session with the WebSocket?

I feel like I am missing some cardinal rule that may be so basic I have missed it out so apologies if it's obvious.

I'm using python 3.8

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? You may need a lock to protect access to the dataframe.

Comment: Inspired by your mention of threads, does this mean I should be generating child thread to handle the execution of the defined function?

Comment: Whether you should depends on what your application does. But *if* you do, you may need a lock to mediate access to shared data like this.